# CSS doesn't work after div id swap with js

Tags: javascript, html, css

Im trying to keep css working after swapping div id with js replace. I can't really figure it out i don't know what's wrong at all. Actually it's so simple that i don't even know what to think ...

```
<style>#WD4 { color:red; }</style>
<div id="60b0b9b1">qww4t</div>
<script>var x = document.body.innerHTML;x = x.replace('60b0b9b1', 'WD4');</script>
```

I just want color to apply. Im sure there's even more than one way around I just can't get it.
Big thanks in advance.

I actually forgot a few important things:

- There are more than just one divs with 'WD4' ID
- I can't edit document i can only inject my javascript code
- I can't edit styles either

Comment: Why are you not using WD4 as the ID to begin with? (Or WD3 whichever you actually want to use )

Comment: This seems like a very strange way to do anything with styles by changing ID. Perhaps an explanation of the higher level issues would give you a better solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the element by `id`:

```
document.getElementById("60b0b9b1").id = 'WD4';
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/p5dfepzd/1/)

And your css is looking for `#WD3` not `#WD4`

Comment: Does it make any difference if I replace div id using your technique or mine? Well omitting a little bit of performance which I don't really care about there's no difference. It doesn't work for styles for both of them

Comment: @NadiaKrawczyk the code you posted isnt working when I try it: [http://jsfiddle.net/p5dfepzd/4/](http://jsfiddle.net/p5dfepzd/4/) even when you switch the `id` in the CSS

Comment: I see, that's really confusing, I have to apologize though because I had noscript enabled and fiddle didn't really work for me. But I can see that your fiddle is working pretty nice and I assumed it doesn't earlier because I tried to reproduce it without any success. Big thanks I'll try once again.

Comment: And one more thing that I figured out and it may make you laugh is that the problem was caused by me trying to use id selector (#) for class. So i tried to make some class red when using # selector. As they say better late than never.

Answer (score 2):

looks like you need to adjust your style to #WD4

Personally I would just add a css class to the element and not style the unique ID of the element.